# How to dynamically build and store complex linq queries against a list of hierarchical objects?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, dynamic-linq

I have a list of objects in a hierarchical structure. I want to build complex LINQ queries against that object list based on "conditions" a client company sets and are stored in the database. So I need to build these at run time, but because they will be run repeatedly whenever the client's users update or refresh their data I would like to store the LINQ queries in objects rather than rebuild them each time.

I have looked at ScottGu's Blog about [Dynamic LINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).
Also this article about using [expression trees](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/dynamic-linq-queries-with-expression-trees/).

Neither of these appear to provide an adequate solution, but I may not be understanding them adequately. I'm afraid that I'm trying to use LINQ when I should consider other options.

My object hierarchy:

```
WorkOrder[]
    Field[]
    Task[]
        Field[]
```

Here is an example of a LINQ query that I would like to store and execute. I can reasonably build this format based on the database records that define the conditions.

```
var query =
from wo in WorkOrders
from woF in wo.Fields
from task in wo.Tasks
from taskF in task.Fields
from taskF2 in task.Fields
where woF.Name == "System Status"
    && woF.Value.Contains("SETC")
    && taskF.Name == "Material"
    && taskF.Value == "Y"
    && taskF2.Name == "Planner"
    && taskF2.Value == "GR5259"
select new
{
    wo_id = wo.ID,
    task_id = task.ID
};
```

A few considerations.

- Depending on the complexity of the user defined conditions I may or may not need to pull from the different object lists: the "froms" are dynamic.
- Note that in this example I pulled twice from the task.fields[] so I aliased it two times.
- The example LINQ structure allows me to have complex ANDs, ORs, parenthesis, etc. that I don't believe is practical with Dynamic Chaining or Expression Trees.

In my code I envision:

```
//1) Retrieve business rules from DB. I can do this.

//2) Iterate through the business rules to build the linq queries.
foreach (BusinessRule br in BusinessRules) {
    //Grab the criteria for the rule from the DB. 

    //Create a linq to object query based on the criteria just built.
    //Add this query to a list for later use.
}

...Elsewhere in application.

//Iterate through and execute the linq queries in order to apply business rules to data cached in the application.
foreach (LinqQuery q in LinqQueries) {
    //Execute the query

    //Apply business rule to the results.
}
```

Thank you very much for your thoughts, effort and ideas.

Comment: What do you mean "store them in objects"?  Store what?  The result of the query?  Use a cache.  The expression?  What would you store?  It's an expression.  Are you trying to say that you want to dynamically ***compose*** queries?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Ideally, when the application begins I could dynamically build the LINQ queries I need and store them in a static class and then reference them for repeated use. My list of WorkOrder objects will frequently change and I want to execute the LINQ queries against it in order to perform business rules against those particular objects.

Comment: Just to be clear: I want to store the LINQ query definition, not the results.

Comment: Your query object is the stored LINQ query. What do you mean exactly by "store"?

Comment: Have you tried the PredicateBuilder? http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Thank you Guillaume.
I think I have 3 questions/steps:
1) At runtime build linq-to-object queries as complex as my example.  
2) "Store" those definitions so I'm not constantly rebuilding them. As you mention, this might be irrelevant. As long as I can reference for re-use as needed.  
3) Execute the linq queries against my object list.

Comment: Yes, the query object in your code snippet is a reference to the query, store that reference wherever you'll need it and you won't need to rebuild it. I highly recommend performance test data before you build anything more complex. It's highly possible rebuilding the LINQ queries every time is trivial, so that optimizing that would be a net liability.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out PredicateBuilder. I will look into it more, but i'm using LINQ to Object not LINQ to SQL, so instead of IQueryable I expect IEnumerable. How would I, at runtime, build the example query I provided and execute it?

Comment: I can cook up an example. What would the parameter list look like when you receive them from your clients?

Comment: So many thanks for your thoughts and patience Guillaume. I'd be very grateful for an example. Pretend I pass the following string to you: how would you create the linq-to-object query?  

from wo in WorkOrders
from woF in wo.Fields
from task in wo.Tasks
from taskF in task.Fields
from taskF2 in task.Fields
where woF.Name == "System Status"
    && woF.Value.Contains("SETC")
    && taskF.Name == "Material"
    && taskF.Value == "Y"
    && taskF2.Name == "Planner"
    && taskF2.Value == "GR5259"

Comment: Whatever code generated that string already knows how to build your dynamic query. How did that code receive the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can technically achieve what you need using only LINQ, but the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) is a nice utility class:

```
public enum AndOr
{
    And,
    Or
}

public enum QueryableObjects
{
    WorkOrderField,
    TaskField
}

public class ClientCondition
{
    public AndOr AndOr;
    public QueryableObjects QueryableObject;
    public string PropertyName;
    public string PropertyValue;
}

public void PredicateBuilderExample()
{
    var conditions = new List<ClientCondition> {
    {
        new ClientCondition { AndOr = LINQ.AndOr.And,
            QueryableObject = QueryableObjects.WorkOrderField,
            PropertyName = "System Status",
            PropertyValue = "SETC"
        }
    },
    {
        new ClientCondition{AndOr = AndOr.And,
            QueryableObject = QueryableObjects.TaskField,
            PropertyName = "Material",
            PropertyValue = "Y"
        }
    },
    {
        new ClientCondition{AndOr = AndOr.Or,
            QueryableObject = QueryableObjects.TaskField,
            PropertyName = "Planner",
            PropertyValue = "GR5259"
        }
    }
    };

    //Obviously this WorkOrder object is empty so it will always return empty lists when queried.
    //Populate this yourself.
    var WorkOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();

    var wofPredicateBuilder = PredicateBuilder.True<WorkOrderField>();
    var tfPredicateBuilder = PredicateBuilder.True<TaskField>();

    foreach (var condition in conditions)
    {
        if (condition.AndOr == AndOr.And)
        {
            if (condition.QueryableObject == QueryableObjects.WorkOrderField)
            {
                wofPredicateBuilder = wofPredicateBuilder.And(
                    wof => wof.Name == condition.PropertyName &&
                        wof.Value.Contains(condition.PropertyValue));
            }
        }
        if (condition.AndOr == AndOr.Or)
        {
            if (condition.QueryableObject == QueryableObjects.TaskField)
            {
                tfPredicateBuilder = tfPredicateBuilder.Or(
                    tf => tf.Name = condition.PropertyName &&
                        tf.Value.Contains(condition.PropertyValue));
            }
        }
        //And so on for each condition type.
    }

    var query = from wo in WorkOrders
                from woF in wo.Fields.AsQueryable().Where(wofPredicateBuilder)
                from task in wo.Tasks
                from taskF in task.Fields.AsQueryable().Where(tfPredicateBuilder)
                select new
                {
                    wo_id = wo.ID,
                    task_id = task.ID
                };
}
```

Note that I use the enums to limit the possible conditions your clients can send you. To have a truly dynamic queryable engine, you will need to use Reflection to ensure the object names you receive are valid. That seems like a rather large scope, and at that point I would recommend researching a different approach, such as [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/).

Also note that the order of And and Ors matters significantly. Essentially you are allowing your customers to build SQL queries against your data, and that usually ends in tears. It's your job to limit them to the proper set of conditions they should be querying.

Comment: Yes, but please take it one more step. I keep hitting the road block of multiple criteria from, for example, the task fields. In the example I provided I showed 2. How would I do that? If I understand your code you're only joining to the task fields once. I might have 0 or X number of criteria to filter from.

Comment: I added the OR condition for your task field. As an exercise, try adding the And condition for a Task field. Your code should go where my comment //And so on for each... is.

Comment: I've updated the original question adding how I envision the code.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but it doesn't work for me with the 2nd criteria for task fields. As I it it ends up being "PropertyName==Material && PropertyValue==Y && PropertyName==Planner && PropertyValue==GR5259. This will never be true. Thanks again Guillaume

Comment: I modified the query to join to task.fields a 2nd time and it works. So how to add the "from" statements dynamically?
var query = from wo in WorkOrders
from woF in wo.Fields.AsQueryable().Where(wofPredicateBuilder)
from task in wo.Tasks
from taskF in task.Fields.AsQueryable().Where(tfPredicateBuilder)
from taskF2 in task.Fields.AsQueryable().Where(f2 => f2.Name == "Planner" && f2.Value == "WE5259")
select new
{
   wo_id = wo.ID,
   task_id = task.ID};

Comment: @Jeff I don't know how to do that. I can think of a way to add 'from' clauses to your LINQ query, but it requires anonymous types, and anonymous types cannot cross the function boundary, so you wouldn't be able to use those queries "elsewhere in the application" like you want.

Comment: @Jeff Also, you don't need to join on task.fields 2 times. All you need is the "OR" predicate.

Comment: Thank you Guillaume, but an OR is not the same logical result that I want. In the example I provided you see that I need the tasks that have both a field named Material with a value of Y AND have a field named Planner with a value of XXXX

Comment: @Jeff My mistake. It sounds like you want complex dynamic queries. That's hard to create, and very hard to maintain. Please post the answer once you figure it out. I am very curious to learn how you pull it off.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion with Guillaume I would only suggest to pay attention to the type of the resulting query when playing around with advanced dynamic query generation. If you are changing the shape of what is being returned via `Select`, `Aggregate`, or one of the other methods you will expect your inner type to change accordingly. If you are just filtering with Where you can keep adding on as many additional cases you want unless you want OR behavior then things like PredicateBuilder helps. If you want to pull in more data via `Join`, `Zip`, ... then you are either doing so to filter, add to the rows returned, and possibly change the shape of the data.

I've done a lot of this in the past and had most success focusing on specific helper methods that allow for common cases that I need and then leaning on linq expression trees and patterns such as the visitor pattern to allow custom expression built at runtime.